# Apache Airflow failure email not including logs

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow 2.6.1.  A task failed recently and the email alert fired, sending me:

```
Try 1 out of 1
Exception:
Failed attempt to attach error logs
Log: Link
```

The "Link" takes me to the logs in the Airflow web UI when I click it.  There I see the details I'm expecting about why the task failed.  That part is good.

How can I debug the message "Failed attempt to attach error log"?  In case it's relevant, the failing task is a BashOperator.